How can i get 7 days of costing per location in Azure?
I have a subscription and a number of services in different locations, for examp west europe , etc
But I have 2 different resource groups in West Europe , Europe1 and Europe2 and they have different services in them.
I want to get the cost of the resource group in that location , so for example OUTPUT WOULD BE
West Europe
 RG: Europe1 $500
     Europe2: $800

I was wanting to get the cost per location for a specific date range that is specified by the user.
How can i get this data ?
I have tried the api Azure-cost , but cant seem to see how i can specify the date range ?

Note that, as written, this is off-topic: it's just a requirement. Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]

As this seems to be a PowerShell question, I'll provide the code in PS
Firstly, there are two PowerShell modules you need
Install-Module 'Az' -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module 'Az.Billing' -Scope CurrentUser

Afterwards lets specify the timeframe and the resource group (alternativly prompt the user for input)
$firstDay = (GET-DATE -Day 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$lastDay = ((GET-DATE).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$resourceGroup = "my-awesome-rg"

Now you can ask the Azure Cost API for the consumption (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.billing/get-azconsumptionusagedetail?view=azps-12.3.0)
$currentCost = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup -StartDate $firstDay -EndDate $lastDay -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property PretaxCost -Sum).Sum

If you need to have the data for a location it gets bit more tricky as you need to aggregate and filter a bit.
$location = "westeurope"
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription 
$currentCostSum = 0
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
  $null = Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription.Id
  $resourceGroups = az group list --query "[?location=='$location']"
  foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
    $currentCost = 0
    $currentCost = (Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup $firstDay -EndDate $lastDay -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property PretaxCost -Sum).Sum
    $currentCostSum = $currentCostSum + $currentCost   
  }
}

However this assumes that you only have resources in the resource group of one location. You would need to see how you can filter further in the Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail cmdlet. But I hope this helps to get you started.

The OP hasn't shown any work - just a requirement. The question is off-topic as written (as I commented under the question). Please don't answer off-topic questions (plus, you're not answering any specific question - you're providing a custom solution)
